# Creating a profile for a registered user in node.js

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, mongodb

I have a user model which I store in MongoDB and I wish to create a unique user profile for each user that registers to my site.

This is the user model:

```
var UserSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    username: {
        type: String,
        index:true,
        unique: true
    },
    password: {
        type: String
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        unique: true
    },
    name: {
        type: String
    },
    avatar: {
        type: String
    }
});
```

tried doing something like the following code from a video I watched, but it didn't work at all:

```
router.get("/:username", function(req,res){
    User.findOne({where: {username: req.params.username}}, function(err,foundUser){
        if(err){
            req.flash("error", "Something went wrong.");
            return res.redirect("/");
        }
        res.render('profile',{user:foundUser});
    })
});
```

while "/:username" has to be the user's username.

How can I create a user profile after he registers, and let other users see it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I didn't understand what are you asking?

Comment: After I register, the website will create a profile for me and I could enter it.

Answer (score 0):

I think your handler should be:

```
router.get("/:username", function(req,res){
    User.findOne({username: req.params.username}, function(err,foundUser){
        if(err){
            req.flash("error", "Something went wrong.");
            return res.redirect("/");
        }
        res.render('profile',{user:foundUser});
    })
});
```

Comment: It still **GET**s "/:username" instead of the actual username.

Comment: :username means it's a dynamic parameter, it can be anything. req.params.username will be its value.

Comment: That's right, and the thing is that it doesn't work. It just writes it as it's a string and doesn't get the req.params.username value it should.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code.

```
 router.get("/:username", function (req, res) {
  User.findOne({
    username: req.params.username
  }, function (err, foundUser) {
    if (err) {
      req.flash("error", "Something went wrong.");
      return res.redirect("/");
    }
    if (foundUser.length == 0) //Means no data found
    {
      //Write code for when no such user is there
    }
    res.render('profile', {
      user: foundUser
    });
  })
});
```

This code will take username, if it doesn't exit create it else will do whatever you were doing

Comment: I'm sorry if that's a rookie question, because that's what I'm, but what do you mean by object of data?

Comment: object means this
{
  username: "username",
  password: "password",
  email: "email",
  name: "name",
  avatar: "whatever it is"
}

Comment: oh, i've already done it:

if(errors){
  res.render('register',{
   errors:errors
  });
 } else {
  var newUser = new User({
   name: name,
   email:email,
   username: username,
   password: password,
   avatar: avatar
  });

Comment: it adds the details from the registration page to my local mongoDB.
When I enter my profile, it gets only the user.email tho, for some reason.

Comment: try this before res.render
console.log(foundUser);
and tell me what is output in terminal

Comment: The output is null

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170050/discussion-between-ayush-mahajan-and-stackoverlow).